# Fitting integral of complicated function into a dataset

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, fitting

So, I'm trying to adjust a model to an experiment, this model, more specifically:

[image]

While:

[image]

The only parameter to be adjusted is I, the problem here is, I not only need to plot this with all the errors and so, as I need to fit the integral of this in respect of "r" from 0 to 2*pi, with "d" being the x-axis value.

I'm extremely new to Mathematica, I've been barely able to just plot the data points with errors, without any fitting whatsoever, how should I proceed? And, is it feasible at all?

Oh,and E_1/E_2 are complete elliptic integrals of first and second kind, respectively…

Edit: [This](https://pastebin.com/MLrjf96d) is my current code, however it doesn't wields me more than a bunch of warnings and errors, and, this is the actual model implemented:
[image]

Comment: Can you post the data as well?

Comment: [Of course!](https://pastebin.com/uezbaFrT).And, [this](https://pastebin.com/zEbYZcn9) is the code I've been (trying to) working in, in the last hours.

Comment: In your code `Sqrt[_]` (like all functions) must use square brackets rather than parentheses. And the call to the function `field` must include its arguments.

Comment: @BobHanlon Oh, Thank you! Such a simple problem… C++ Habits… However, I have a new problem, [here's my current code](https://pastebin.com/5JuUpFW3), now it gives me "FindFit::fitm: Unable to solve for the fit parameters; the design matrix is nonrectangular, non-numerical, or could not be inverted.", and I don't really know what it means.

Comment: [New updated current version…](https://pastebin.com/KZ3fg3pn), I'm still not sure what the problem may be, I've tried all the suggestions I could find, and, yet, nothing…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download your [`data file`](https://pastebin.com/uezbaFrT) and delete the `.txt` extension before importing.

```
data = Import["/Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/coil_datawu.csv"];
```

The `data` then consists of lists of pairs of numbers rather than a string.

```
Union[{Head[#], Length[#], And @@ (NumberQ /@ #)} & /@ data]

(* {{List, 2, True}} *)

(* mu=4 e-7*Pi *)

mu = 4*10^-7 * Pi; (* Assuming you intended this *)
Radius = 0.149 // Rationalize;
radius = 0.0582 // Rationalize;
frequency = 8313 // Rationalize;
```

There is no need to restrict the arguments of `field` to be numeric since it does not use numeric techniques.

```
field[r_, x_, mu_, Radius_, frequency_] := 
  mu*frequency*
   Sqrt[2]/(2*Pi*
      Sqrt[x^2 + (Radius + r)^2])*((Radius^2 - x^2 - 
         r^2)/(x^2 + (r - Radius)^2)*
      EllipticE[Sqrt[4*r*Radius*(x^2 + (Radius + r)^2)^(-1)]] + 
     EllipticK[Sqrt[4*r*Radius*(x^2 + (Radius + r)^2)^(-1)]]);
```

However, define the `model` using [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html) which then necessitates that the arguments to `model` be numeric. Note that `i` must also be an argument and the integrand should not be enclosed in `List` brackets.

```
Clear[model]

model[i_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ, mu_?NumericQ, Radius_?NumericQ, 
  frequency_?NumericQ] := 
 2*i*Pi*NIntegrate[field[r, x, mu, Radius, frequency], {r, 0, radius}]

solution = FindFit[data, model[i, x, mu, Radius, frequency], {{i, 0.7}}, x]

(* {i -> 12.7577} *)

{xmin, xmax} = MinMax[data[[All, 1]]];
```

However, the model does not appear to fit the data.

```
Plot[model[i, x, mu, Radius, frequency] /. solution,
 {x, xmin, xmax},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[3], Point[data]}]
```

[image]

[`NonlinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html) produces the same results.

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, model[i, x, mu, Radius, frequency], {{i, 0.7}}, 
   x];

nlm["BestFitParameters"]

(* {i -> 12.7577} *)

Plot[nlm[x], {x, xmin, xmax},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[3], Point[data]}]
```

[image]